# Problem connecting to SQL Server from Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

My program didn't give errors but it didn't connect to SQL Server. Which processes must I run in SQL Server Configuration Manager besides browser? Should I run SQL Server agent and SQL Server (mssqlserver)?

Comment: Please show us your code. In java, you'll have an error if connection to the server fail.

Comment: @Nicolas Bousquet i was wrong, the problem was not with connection to sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need the JDBC driver that matches your vendor to connect Java to any relational database.

Microsoft has [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724) for SQL Server; [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) is an open source alternative.

Here's a [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) to the JDBC tutorial to get you started.